# Outlook 2007 constantly disconnected

Tags: exchange, outlook

I have exchange on my server it has been working fine for over the last year but as of 2 days it is now saying in my outlook 2007 it is displaying disconnected and it doesnt want to connect. Any ideas how to reconnect to my exchange server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your network connection to your Exchange server. Can you ping your Exchange server from your client using the hostname? If you can proceed, if you cannot then you have a network layer issue between your client and Exchange.

Hold down CTRL and right-click the Outlook icon in your system tray and choose "Connection Status". You should see your Exchange server under general and it should say "Disconnected" if you aren't connected. Go ahead and click "Reconnect" to attempt to reconnect.

Comment: i can connect to the server from the workstation. when i right click the outlook in the system tray there is nothing in the connection status it appears to be blank

Comment: Hold down CTRL and right-click the Outlook status icon in the system tray.

Comment: i did that. Anyway i found out the cause there was little space on the disk so it disabled a service and unmounted the First storage mailbox so i just had to mount it and restart the service

Answer (score 0):

If you can ping your exchange server then

1. go to regedit and
2. delete the profilelist without the admin profilelist and
3. on the `cmd` prompt execute `gpupdate`

Reconfigure your outlook. The problem should be resolved then.